# Why can't I substract from a char when dealing with a pointer string?

Tags: c

So basically I am trying to uppercase all the letters in a string. Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {
    char *input = "Quebec";

    // Method 1
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
        if (input[i] <= 'z' && input[i] >= 'a')
        {
            input[i] -= 32;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", input);
}
```

I keep getting an exit code 139 and when debugging it says on the line `input[i] -= 32;` "Signal = SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)"

When I replace `char *input = "Quebec";` with `char input[256] = "Quebec";`, everything works fine.

I'm confused.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s?noredirect=1&lq=1